# Why is my AJAX request a PUT request in dev but a GET request when running tests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara

Within my rails app I make an AJAX PUT request (using Coffeescript), which works correctly in my dev environment. When I inspect the button that, when clicked, triggers the AJAX request using Firefox it looks like this:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
      minutes: minutes,
      appt_id: appt_id
    }
});
```

However, when I run an integration test that clicks the same button and I inspect the button in Firefox (I stopped the test in the middle using byebug), the AJAX request looks like this:

```
return $.get(url, {
    minutes: minutes,
    appt_id: appt_id
  });
```

I just changed the request from using GET to using PUT (it works when I tested it manually), and the test passed when it was using GET, but after changing it to use PUT the test is failing with the following error:

```
1.2) Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

          ActionController::RoutingError:
            No route matches [GET] "/appointments/9998/put_away"
```

Why is the AJAX request in the testing environment getting changed from a PUT to a GET request, and how can I fix this so that my tests pass? Thanks!

I am using Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.2.4p230 and RSpec 3.4.4, as well as Selenium and Capybara for testing.

Comment: how did your code change?  The first example code is different than the second!  Also could you post the network tab requests and responses?

Comment: @dm03514 I replaced `$.get(url, { minutes: minutes, appt_id: appt_id } )` with `$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'PUT',
      data: { minutes: minutes, appt_id: appt_id }
      })` and changed my routes from `get 'send_more_minutes_message' ` to `put 'send_more_minutes_message'`.

Comment: Did you pre compile the assets in the test env previously? If so it can sometimes stop rails from detecting changes in the JS so it continues using old versions

Comment: @TomWalpole I don't recall doing that in the test env intentionally, but it's possible. I always precompile before deploying, but not specifically in the test env. Should I try that now? If so, how do I only precompile in the test env? Thanks!

Comment: @jackerman09 Check public/assets/ for a manifest file -- possibly something like  .sprockets-manifest*.json  and try deleting it - you shouldn't need to precompile in the test env it should handle asset compilation automatically but I've seen cases where if it has been done it prevents future changes from being detected.  You can also try deleting everything else in public/assets too

Comment: @TomWalpole deleting the manifest file worked, thanks! If you set it as an answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you precompile your assets you probably have a manifest file -- possibly .sprockets-manifest*.json -- in public/assets.  The presence of that file can prevent the test environment from detecting changes in your assets, and therefore not serving up the latest JS in tests.  Deleting the manifest file should force the changes to be recognized and served up next time you run the tests.